# Не работает mysqli_real_escape_string

Tags: php, mysql, sql, ajax, post

Вот, где я сталкиваюсь с пробоемой:

Есть форма, где пользователь вводит информацию, которая потом передается через ajax запрос и на php файле обработчике получает значения POST и сохраняет в бд.

Код получения в обработчике:

```
$user = $_POST['user'];
$note = $_POST['note'];
$date = date('Y-m-d');

if(!empty($user) && !empty($note)) {})
```

При этом все работает как надо. Но если добавить `mysqli_real_escape_string` сюда

```
$note = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['note']);
```

то код перестает работать.

Как в этом случае лучше поступить? Как защииться от иньекций, не используя pdo?

Comment: Могу ошибаться ,но добавлять подобную функцию лучше перед самим запросом в базу, то есть в теле условия(if) . Если не сработает отпишись

Comment: Если Вы имели ввиду так:
     $res = mysqli_query($connection, "INSERT INTO notes (userhash, note, date) VALUES ('$user', 'mysqli_real_escape_string($note)', '$date')");

То не сработало.

Comment: Надо хотя бы __мануал открыть__ и увидеть там __правильный набор аргументов__ - https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.real-escape-string.php#refsect1-mysqli.real-escape-string-parameters.

Comment: Не нужно строить из себя умника. Если я пишу, что не могу разобраться, это не значит, что я не видел этот мануал. Можно просто объяснить, в чем проблема?

Comment: Проблема видимо в том, что вы не понимаете что написано в мануале.

Comment: судя по всему вы тоже, раз не можете адекватно разъяснить...

Comment: Так вам и нельзя объяснить. Вы же не понимаете. В документации же написано русскому по черному порядок аргументов функции `mysqli_real_escape_string`, но вы его осознанно игнорируете. И зачем вам escape_string, если в mysqli есть подготовленные запросы?